# How to sort a n by 1 dimensional matrix and after sorting get the initial index of a value?

Tags: matlab, sorting

How to sort a list and get the initial index of a value in matlab.

```
e.g
orignal A=[40;30;20;50;60]
sorted A=[20;30;40;50;60]
indices of sorted A in orignal A =[3;2;1;4;5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

[sorted, indices] = sort(A);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second output:

```
   [~,i]=sort([40;30;20;50;60])
```

The tilda means that the first output is ignored.